# Cannot decrypt GPG file after installing GPG Suite from GPG Tools

Tags: macos, encryption, gpg

I have installed GPG Suite by GPG Tools on my Mac. I sent my public key to my associate, who encrypted a file and sent it to me. The file, `myfile.gpg` is now sitting on my desktop and I'm told by my associate that I just have to double-click on it, enter my private key, and the file will be decrypted. Sounds reasonable, but it doesn't work.

I double-click on `myfile.gpg` and OS X reports there is no application to open the file. I restarted my Mac and the problem still exists.

Do I need to manually setup a file association?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Assigning Files

Your Mac should have an association with a *.gpg file. 
The appropiate service is named `GPGServices.service` and can be found in `/Library/Services/`. To manually assign the file extension to a application or service click on the myfile.gpg and then <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.

Now you can chose a application with which the file should be open with.[image: File Info]

If you click and hold the drop down menu, chose "Other ..." and a dialog will open. Click <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> and type `/Library/Services`.
Chose `GPGServices.service`, change for all and close the Info window.
If you can't find GPGServices you may have a corrupted or old installation. In this case install the GPG Suite again.

## Decrypting with a terminal

To decrypt the file you can also use a Terminal.

Open Spotlight and type "Terminal.app"(or open a Finder > Applications > Utilities > Terminal.app) and click on it. You will see the command line.
Type `gpg -d`(mind the space after `-d`) and drag the file into the terminal. Hit enter and you will be asked for you password.

### Example

```
gpg -d myfile.gpg
```